# wbadmin systemstate parameter

Tags: backup, powershell, windows-backup

I run a powershell-based backup script using wbadmin on different systems (i.e. Windows 7 Professional / Windows 2008 R2 / Windows 8.1 / Windows 2012R2). In this script, i utilize the -systemstate parameter which should be working for Windows 7 and newer versions according to technet (https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc742083%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

When i run **wbadmin start backup -include:C: -systemstate -backuptarget:D:** on my local Windows 7 x64 Professional machine it returns an error, because wbadmin does not know the parameter **-systemstate**.

Running the same command on a Windows 2012R2 machine worked like a charm. So I thought, there must be different versions of wbadmin shipped with each operating system, and I added a function, that checks if the current OS is Win7. If Win7 is detected, the **-systemstate** parameter will not be passed to wbadmin and the script runs fine.

Now a Windows 8.1 machine has thrown the same error on my script, saying that **-systemstate** is not a valid parameter. I've done some research and could really not find anything helpfull related to the parameter. There are different versions of wbadmin shipped with different versions of windows, which can be identified only by the copyright information when calling **wbadmin /?**. The version number returned by **wbadmin /?** is always 1.0 but the year of the copyright differs.

Since there is no further documentation on technet (that I'm aware of), I'd like to ask if anyone knows, what the exact requirements are needed for using the **-systemstate** switch.

Comment: Try this - leave the -include:C: off and try this command ==> wbadmin start systemstatebackup -backupTarget:D:

Comment: @whs Thanks for the hint, I looked into the start systemstatebackup parameter. Only downsight is, that if i want to use other parameters as from start backup (-vssfull, -allcritical -quiet) they dont seem to be included in that option - at least they are not quite good documented by technet

Answer (score 0):

wbadmin has different capabilities depending on the OS.
The quickest way to check is entering "wbadmin start backup" . This will display all available options for this operation. In case of Windows 7, no -systemstate parameter is shown and thus not available.

Comment: But if I pass it, it will return in an error and thus not be executed by the backup script. My actual solution is to check for the OS the script is running on and pass the correct parameters - the script itself is used by various customers with different operating systems, but I wanted to keep a single script to maintain.